# IOS iphone 6 screen and tiny Font sizes

Tags: html, css, ios, fonts

Could anybody direct me how to correctly manage the fonts on mobile devices.

Currently my Font-Size is in PX. and i am also using media queries. Which look great on dektop and the page is responsive and the fonts are enlarged on small screen sizes.

However on an Iphone 6 , the screen does not go into Responsive as the screen size is 1200px + and so unfortunatly the fonts remain very small.

I have little idea how to further approach this problem. as any attempts i make to Compensate the font sizes on the iphone become greatly enlarged on Desktop.

iv done as much researh as i can get my head round includining using other methods of Font-size - i.e VW , Rem , EM ect and all have failed to produce consistant , readable fonts on the iphone.

i would list the code but its an awful lot at present, so i will try to offer what i can.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

here is the code for the top banner.

HTML:

```
<body>

    <div class='maindiv'> 

        <?php 
        //TOP BANNER
        include('../../innerelements/topbanner/html/topbanner.php');
        
        //LOGO & SEARCH BAR
        include('../../innerelements/Searchbar/html/searchbar.php');
        
        
        ?>
    
    </div>
    
</body>
```

**PHP Included file - Topbanner.php**

```
<div class='topbanner'>
        
        <div id='leftmenu' class='leftmenu'>
            <div class='leftmenuinnername' >Hello  <text class='accountname'> matthew </text> </div>
            <div class='leftmenuinner' >Daily Deals</div>
            <div class='leftmenuinner' >Brand Outlet</div>
            <div class='leftmenuinner' >Help & Contact</div>
        </div>
        
        
        <div id='rightmenu' class='rightmenu'>
            <div class='rightmenuinner' >Sell</div>
            <div class='rightmenuinner' >Watch List</div>
            <div class='rightmenuinner' >My Vbay</div>
            <div class='rightmenuinner' ><div class='bellicon'></div></div>
            <div class='rightmenuinner' ><div class='carticon'></div></div>
        </div>
        
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;

}


.maindiv{
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    MIN-WIDTH: 600px;
    display: block;
}
.topbanner{
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,Sans-serif !important;
    font-size: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
    text-align: left;
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    /* line-height:14px; */
}

.accountname{
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-right: 36px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.leftmenu{
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    padding: 6px;
    margin-left: 8px;
    margin-right: 4px;
    display: flex;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.leftmenuinner{
    height: auto;
    padding: 0px 4px 0px 4px;
    margin-left: 6px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    overflow: hidden;
    word-break: keep-all;
}

  .leftmenuinnername{
    height: auto;
    padding: 0px 4px 0px 4px;
    margin-left: 6px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    overflow: hidden;
    word-break: keep-all;
    }

.leftmenuinner:hover{
color:dodgerblue;
}


.rightmenu{
    /* right: 0px; */
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    padding: 6px;
    margin-left: 4px;
    margin-right: 18px;
    display: flex;
    line-height: 20px;
}
 
.rightmenuinner{
    padding: 0px 4px 0px 4px;
    margin-left: 8px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}


.rightmenuinner:hover{
color:dodgerblue;
}


.bellicon{
    position: relative;
    min-width: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 20px;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(../assets/icons/bellicon.png);
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.bellicon:hover{
    background-image: url('../assets/icons/belliconhover.png');

}




.carticon{
    position:relative;
    min-width: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 20px;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('../assets/icons/carticon.png');
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.carticon:hover{
    background-image: url('../assets/icons/carticonhover.png');

}




@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  
  .topbanner{
    font-size:300%;
    justify-content: space-between;
    }
  
  
  .leftmenuinner{
  display:none;
  }
  
   .leftmenuinnername{
    float:left;
    line-height: 30px;
    }
  
  .rightmenuinner{
     min-width: 30px;
     min-height: 30px;
     line-height: 30px;
     }
  
  .vbaylogo{
      display:none;
  }
  
  .searchcontainer{
      font-size:20px;
      margin-left:0px;
  }
  
  
  .catagory1{
      
  }
  
  
  .searchbutton{
     font-size:20px;  
  }
  
  
  select{
      font-size:20px;
  }
  
  .searchbarinput{
      font-size:20px;
  }
  
  
  
}
```

if any1 can help i would be greatfull.

Thank you.

Comment: What do your metatags look like? Also, why are you not setting font-size: 100% on html tag and then a font size on body? These set default font size which you can then refer to using "inherit" through the rest of your styles so the cascade is kept.

Answer (score 3):

Just use this in your head:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`.

This gives the browser instructions on how to control the page's dimensions and scaling.

Comment: @ShaneDee 
Hey, I'm very glad it worked out! If you want to show other users that they have to do this to solve their problem, you can click the tick next to the votes! Have a nice day! :)